# Memory upgrade suggestions by Crucial

Tags: laptop, memory

I'm hoping to upgrade my ASUS X550LC laptop with an additional memory.

As possible upgrades for my laptop I got suggestions by crucial software [here](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/scanview/CCD8477E31D926C3).  For compatible memory it shows only 8 GB memory sticks; one can be found [here](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/x550lc/CT5236491) .

[image]

I suppose, although it's not shown this 4 GB memory [here](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/ct51264bf160b) will also be compatible. Am I wrong and what are the other compatible 4GB memories for ASUS X550LC laptops?

The reason why I'm not going to buy 8 GB one is, since it's DDR3, with assumption that it would not be compatible with new laptops hence, spending much on that would be useful and additional 4GB ram (current memory - 4 GB) would be enough for general purposes. Any comment on this would also be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.